# How to Print Current Date in myTeamsMessage.title of pymsteams API

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-teams

I am trying to send automatic message through Python "pymsteams" API but i got stuck at one place. I want to set current Date in title of my automated teams message, but not able to do. Can anyone  help me here. I have shared my code for more clarity. Thanks!!

```
import pymsteams
from datetime import date
 
# You must create the connectorcard object with the Microsoft Webhook URL
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("<<Webhook url passing here>>")

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
# Add text to the message.
myTeamsMessage.title("d1- Americas Virtual Stand-up")
myTeamsMessage.text("this is my text")

# send the message.
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this just used Python3's f-Strings

```
import pymsteams
from datetime import date
 
# You must create the connectorcard object with the Microsoft Webhook URL
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("<<Webhook url passing here>>")

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
# or user this formate
# d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
# Add text to the message.
myTeamsMessage.title(f"{d1} - Americas Virtual Stand-up")
myTeamsMessage.text("this is my text")

# send the message.
myTeamsMessage.send()
```